# Example of a projective space

Tags: abstract-algebra, analytic-geometry, algebraic-curves

This example is from R. J. Walker - Algebraic Curves.

Let $S$ be the circle $x^2+y^2-y=0$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$

[it passes through $(0,0)$ and $(0,1)$; and also the horizontal lines through these points are tangent to the circle.]

If $P$ is any point on this circle other than $(0,1)$, we take projective coordinates of $P$ to be $(\rho,\rho x)$ where $\rho$ is any non-zero real number and $x$ is the abscissa of the point where line $AP$ cuts X-axis. As projective coordinates of $A$ we take $(0,\rho)$ with $\rho\neq 0$.

**Question:** I do not get what author want to say here. In $(\rho,\rho x$), if $\rho$ is varying over non-zero real numbers, so it is $\rho$ times $(1,x)$; now how this point $(1,x)$ is  obtained from $(0,1)$, the point $P$ and the given circle?

Comment: What is point $A$? Is that $(0,1)$?

Comment: It looks like he is saying that each point on the circle corresponds to a point on the $x$ axis which he takes to be the slope  of a line passing through the origin. So $(0,1)$ (I believe that's $A$) corresponds to the vertical line through the origin and $(1,0)$ corresponds to the line through the origin with slope $1$.

Comment: Does the author define the concept of "projective coordinates"?